# Does android have Class to deal with picture, like mixing color channel, adjusting brightness and etc.?

Tags: android

Does android have any Classes to deal with picture, like mixing color channel, adjusting brightness or sharpness, etc.? 
I know I can implement this kind of function by myself, but if android contains these functions to deal with this, it will be more convenient. Thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might even help you [Follow this link](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/learning/tutorials/)
or even [this](http://www.kpbird.com/2013/09/android-image-filters.html) link.

Here's another nice example which comes with android sdk samples

```
AndroidSdk/samples/android-ApiLevel/HelloEffects
```

Comment: Your answer is pretty helpful. You just give me what I need. Thank you so much.